# Where Is Asterisk FreePBX Video Call Recording File

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I would like to know where can I find (if it does exist) the video file for a call with video.

I already have all the things running properly:

- Call recording enabled for extensions as Force
- Call recording enabled for routes as Force
- Video Support enabled
- Video Codecs checked
- 3CX Softphone calling with video
- 3CX recording the video locally
- WAV file available on FreePBX CRD Reports

Now I would like to have/find the video file (MPEG, H264, etc).

Am I missing some config or it can't be done?

I'm running on FreePBX 13.0.194.2 and Asterisk 13.

Tnx in advance,

Answer (score 0):

By default, all recordings go into the `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/` folder.

Comment: Tnx for your reply but it does not have any video file, just the usual WAV for audio files.